# Multiple Modal Buttons Not Working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my personal website, I have a page for my resume that I want to be interactive.  On this page, I have multiple modal buttons (to show specific job details).  I have tried many different things (like unique id's for each button), but every time I get both buttons to open the same content from the second job shows up for BOTH buttons.  In other words, I can't get the JS to identify the separate button modals to open up.

How do I fix this?  Do I use a for Loop and if so, how does that work?

The code I have is below (and I have messed with the JS code since then, so I know I have work to do on it).

```js
var modalBtnArray = ['0', '1']

function openModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal-' + arguments[0]);
  console.log('openModal was clicked' + modal);
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal-' + arguments[0]);
  console.log('closeModal was clicked' + modal);
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}


for (const element of modalBtnArray) {
  console.log(element);
  var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn-' + element);
  console.log('modalBtn = ' + modalBtn);
  modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal(element));

}


for (const element of modalBtnArray) {
  console.log(element);
  var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn-' + element);
  console.log('closeBtn = ' + closeBtn);
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal(element));
}
```

```css
#modalBtn-0 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

#modalBtn-0:hover {
  background: darkgray;
}

#modalBtn-1 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

#modalBtn-1:hover {
  background: darkgray;
}

#simpleModal-0 {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#simpleModal-1 {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 2px darkgray;
  color: black;
}

#closeBtn-0 {
  color: darkgray;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#closeBtn-0:hover,
#closeBtn-0:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#closeBtn-1 {
  color: darkgray;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#closeBtn-1:hover,
#closeBtn-1:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#resume p.job-details {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Amazon</h4>
<p class="job">Warehouse Worker // July 2020-Present</p>

<button id="modalBtn-0" class="button">More Details</button>
<div id="simpleModal-0" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="closeBtn-0">&times;</span>
    <h3>Job Description</h3>
    <p class="job-details">I scan in vendor products to receiving. I also research and correct any barcode problems with those products>.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h4>Mesquite Independent School District</h4>
<p class="job">Middle School Teacher // February 2016-June 2020 <br> Substitute Teacher // October 2015-February 2016</p>

<button id="modalBtn-1" class="button">More Details</button>
<div id="simpleModal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="closeBtn-1">&times;</span>
    <h3>Job Description</h3>
    <p class="job-details">I taught.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the javascript a bit more reusable what you can do is this.

Add a class to your open modal buttons, preferably starting with `js-`, the js part makes it easy for you and for others to know what elements has javascript attached to them.

Have a data attribute to the buttons with the id of the modal they are gone open/close. Note: I usually do the full `#something`.

Add/remove (toggle) class instead of setting it display none|block by script.

For the purpose of this demo I simplified it for clarity but normally I would probably do the open and close button with the same click event, maybe a if statement checking if `dataset.controls` is undefined then assume it is the close button.

Another observation I made. When styling use classes not ids, as you can see in my example I don't duplicate styling for the same element. Just a note I was a bit sloppy and did not rename all of your classes.

```js
const modalTogglers = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-toggler-action')

modalTogglers.forEach((action) => {
  action.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const modal = document.querySelector(action.dataset.controls)

    if (modal === undefined) {
      console.log('please check your id')
      return
    }

    modal.classList.toggle('modal--is-open')
  })
})

const closeModalActions = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-close-action')

closeModalActions.forEach((action) => {
  action.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const modal = action.closest('.modal')
    console.log('modal: ', modal)
    modal.classList.remove('modal--is-open')
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: darkgray;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border: black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal--is-open {
  display: block;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 2px darkgray;
  color: black;
}

.modal__close-button {
  color: darkgray;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal__close-button:hover,
.modal__close-button:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#resume p.job-details {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Amazon</h4>
<p class="job">Warehouse Worker // July 2020-Present</p>

<button class="button js-modal-toggler-action" data-controls="#simple-modal-1">More Details</button>
<div id="simple-modal-1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="modal__close-button js-modal-close-action">&times;</span>
    <h3>Job Description</h3>
    <p class="job-details">I scan in vendor products to receiving. I also research and correct any barcode problems with those products>.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h4>Mesquite Independent School District</h4>
<p class="job">Middle School Teacher // February 2016-June 2020 <br> Substitute Teacher // October 2015-February 2016</p>

<button class="button js-modal-toggler-action" data-controls="#simple-modal-2">More Details</button>
<div id="simple-modal-2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="modal__close-button js-modal-close-action">&times;</span>
    <h3>Job Description</h3>
    <p class="job-details">I taught.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay will do, @Dejan.S!!